# Getting With helper for offline capabilities to work

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, aws-appsync

Today I started taking a look at the offline capabilities being offered by Appsync and it being my first time I was overwhelmed pretty badly. I spent the day going through several tutorials but they never quite offered enough for me to complete the task or maybe I was just to stupid. Well going back to the amplify github docs I came across this

```
import { buildMutation } from 'aws-appsync';
import { listTodos } from './graphql/queries';
import { createTodo, CreateTodoInput } from './graphql/mutations';

(async () => {
  const result = await client.mutate(buildMutation(client,
    gql(createTodo),
    {
      inputType: gql(CreateTodoInput),
      variables: {
        input: {
          name: 'Use AppSync',
          description: 'Realtime and Offline',
        }
      }
    },
    (_variables) => [ gql(listTodos) ],
    'Todo'));

  console.log(result);
})();
```

so I tried to use that. but I got the error `client is not defined` But I have wrapped my app.js in the apolloprovider

```
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: aws_config.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
  region: aws_config.aws_appsync_region,
  auth: {
    type: aws_config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
    apiKey: aws_config.aws_appsync_apiKey,
  },
  offlineConfig: {
    callback: (err, succ) => {
      if(err) {
        const { mutation, variables } = err;

        console.warn(`ERROR for ${mutation}`, err);
      } else {
        const { mutation, variables } = succ;

        console.info(`SUCCESS for ${mutation}`, succ);
      }
    },
  },
});

const WithProvider = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Rehydrated>
    <ArztRoutes/>
    </Rehydrated>
  </ApolloProvider>
```

which by my understanding passes down the client to all other classes so why do I keep getting this error and how can I resolve it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when wrapping the app in ApolloProvider you still need to define how you are gaining access to the client. E.G. A variable named `client` will not be globally available so you need to grab a handle to it. Looking at the Apollo docs, you should be able to use an `ApolloConsumer` to gain access to the client (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#apollo-consumer).